# Run Time Error '13': Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro file to run a greedy algorithm, that is a heuristic process of assigning the work with the greatest value with to the idle server. The macro should assign 26 works to two workstations running the greedy algorithm.

At first I must determine if the task was assigned and then I must determine which unassigned task has the greatest task time and move on. This should be a pretty straightforward code but I have trouble reading the task times from the spreadsheet which range from (C2:C27). I have written the following code but I get a `Run Time Error '13': Type  mismatch` at the line I have marked with two **:

```
Sub GreedyAlgorithm()

Dim totalA As Integer
Dim totalB As Integer
Dim nbA As Integer
Dim nbB As Integer
Dim maxRN As Integer
Dim maxTT As Integer

totalA = 0
totalB = 0
nbA = 0
nbB = 0



For i = 1 To 26
    maxRN = 0
    maxTT = 0

    For j = 2 To 27
        If IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(j, 5)) Then
            If Sheet2.Cells(j, 3).Value > maxTT Then
            maxRN = j
            **maxTT = Sheet2.Cells(j, 3).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next j

    If totalB > totalA Then
        Sheet2.Cells(maxRN, 5).Value = "A"
        nbA = nbA + 1
        Sheet2.Cells(maxRN, 6).Value = nbA
        totalA = totalA + maxTT
    ElseIf totalB <= totalA Then
        Sheet2.Cells(maxRN, 5).Value = "B"
        nbB = nbB + 1
        Sheet2.Cells(maxRN, 6).Value = nbB
        totalB = totalB + maxTT

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

What might be the reason for this? I have went back to my spreadsheet and manually set the data types as number for my range. This still has not solved the problem.

Comment: What's in cell `Sheet2.Cells(j, 3)` when the error occurs? I betcha it isn't a number. Try stepping through your code in debug mode and watching how your variables evolve ([instructions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)). If that doesn't help, then I suggest you see this for guidance: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is most probably with the data you are trying to assign an `Integer` with. I tried with `3`, and got no issues. Max. Integer value in VBA is *32767*.

I'd suggest to declare the `maxTT` variable as `Long`.

```
Dim maxTT As Long
```

There may be other issues, but without the input it is difficult to guess.

Comment: But that would give an Overflow error, not type mismatch. So that can't be the reason.